# Disable specific form field on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i've to  disable specific fields on button clicks , e.g i've two forms in my  page like this

```
< form method='post' action='' class='myform'>
<input type='text' name='name_0'>
<input type='email' name='email_0'>
<input  class='btn' type='submit'>
</form>

< form method='post' action='' class='myform'>
<input type='text' name='name_1'>
<input type='email' name='email_1'>
<input  class='btn' type='submit'>
</form>
```

using jquery i can disable all fields like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){                            
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $("input").prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

but i dont know how to target specific fields like name_0 ,  email_0 when i first submit  the button , Please help me with this

Comment: Do you want to disable a particular input when you click a button?

Comment: all  inputs in a form which is submitted

Comment: Do you want to get specific fields, or all inputs in a form, or all fields with specific numbers, or all fields of specific type?  Make it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable them you would use the attribute selector:

```
$("input[name='name_0']").prop('disabled', true);
```

[jQuery Attribute Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

If you have multiple items you can combine them:

```
$("input[name='name_0'],input[name='email_0']").prop('disabled', true);
```

Your larger problem is that you're trying to determine a form by clicking on something with a class. In order to narrow this down you could do some DOM traversal:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(event) {
    // which form? this one!
    var currentForm = $(this).closest('form');
    // disable all inputs for this form
    currentForm.find('input').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Now I don't have to know which inputs to disable (if I want to disable all of them). I just have to find the inputs in my button's form.

Comment: Jay your missing a `_`

Comment: Good catch! Thanks @cmorrissey!

Comment: looks good , let  me try this

Answer (score 3):

you should read about [**selectors**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

```
$("input[name=name_0]").prop('disabled', true);
```

or a jquery solution you can target it by using .closest() and .find()

```
$(document).ready(function(){                            
    $('.btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text]").prop('disabled', true);
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=email]").prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

to submit a form and disable all inputs and focus on the next first input on the next form

```
$(document).ready(function(){                            
    $('.myform').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('form').find("input").prop('disabled', true);
        $(this).next('form').find('input:first').focus();
    });

});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/oge2wqf8/)

Comment: can i pass multiple vaues i mean with type if i want to diable button and  email as well so what ?

Comment: @Sikander you can use all inputs with this $(this).closest('form').find('input').prop('disabled', true);  .. I just come with my answer like this cause you already said Disable specific form field on button click

Comment: thanks a lot sir one last thing how can i move focus to next form  if forms are coming in loop

Comment: @Sikander Your're Welcome , Good Luck :)

Comment: @Sikander updated answer